# How to change face background in org mode source block?

Tags: org-mode, faces, doom, customize-face

I've changed background of org mode source blocks, which wasn't picked up by the  vertical lines (rulers) on the left. I've never seen anything like that before and I would be grateful for any suggestions of how to to solve it (that is to make the vertical line character's background the same as the one chosen for the source block).

```
(after! org
...
  (custom-set-faces!
  '((org-block) :background "#141B21")
  )
...
)
```

[image]

I guess that hardcoding the color hex value into the `:background` property wasn't the right practice, but prior to this problem it hasn't caused any other issues.

Comment: What does `C-u C-x =` say about the face when you invoke it on one of the characters of the ruler?

Comment: What @NickD said. Then `M-x customize-face`...

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I didn't know about `what-cursor-position` command. It said `Char: SPC (32, #o40, #x20, part of display " "->"│") point=2262 of 86763 (3%) column=6`. @Drew thanks for suggesting "customize-face" (on doom emacs it's `custom-set-faces!`) I will see if there is some way to change `|` pipe character.